# Why can't I use a UniqueKey for a widget?

Tags: flutter

I don't understand how we are supposed to assign a `UniqueKey` to an object if the compiler doesn't let us.

This code fails if I use the second option:

```dart
body: const Center
(
    child: Note(key: ValueKey('note'), initialValue: 'test'), // WORKS
    child: Note(key: UniqueKey(), initialValue: 'test'), // ERROR
),
```

```
class Note extends StatefulWidget
{
    final String initialValue;

    const Note({required Key key, this.initialValue = ""}) : super(key: key);
```

gives this error:

```
Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is
expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.
```

How can I change this to allow UniqueKey to work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `const` form your code as const requires a constant while while UniqueKey() changes itself.

```
body: Center
(
    child: Note(key: ValueKey('note'), initialValue: 'test'), // WORKS
    child: Note(key: UniqueKey(), initialValue: 'test'), // ERROR
),
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought having `const` on my widgets was required, but I see upon further reading it makes almost zero difference to performance, so I'll stop using it.

Comment: Flutter recommends using const only on canstant values.
Pleased to help you.